# Automatically return verbose results in Python unittest?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, verbose

I know that I can add the `"-v"` to the command line when running a unit test in Python, but how can I modify the following code so that the output is automatically verbose? I tried several variations of adding `-v` to the `unittest.main()` call, with no success.

Python documentation was also unhelpful.

```
import unittest
from TestCalculator import sub

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Sub1(self):
        self.assertEqual(sub(2,4), 2, 'Subtraction test one broke')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main

Comment: Thanks.  I feel a little sheepish about how easy that was.